# Django error: Reverse for '...' not found. '...' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-url-reverse

It gives the error: Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

`urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('App.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include(('django.contrib.auth.urls', 'django.contrib.auth'), namespace='login')),
    path('accounts/', include('Account.urls')),
]
```

`index.html`:

```py
<a href="{% url 'login' %}"><h3 class="agileinfo_sign">Sign In </h3></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```py
<a href="{% url 'login:login' %}"><h3 class="agileinfo_sign">Sign In </h3></a>
```

Hope this small change will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it happened to me when I forgot to add the *login_url = 'view_name'* field of login_required() decorator.

***before:***

```
@login_required()
def checkout_page(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)
```

***after:***

```
@login_required(login_url='your_login_view_name')
def checkout_page(request):
    return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)
```

I hope this can help someone who wants only authenticated users can access the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/account/two_factor/setup/' not found. '/account/two_factor/setup/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Because I set a normal URL to [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag instead of [a URL namespace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#term-instance-namespace) as shown below:

```html
<a href="{% url '/account/two_factor/setup/' %}">Two factor setup</a>
```

So, I set a URL namespace to `url` tag as shown below, then the error was solved:

```html
<a href="{% url '/account/two_factor/setup/' %}">Two factor setup</a>
```

Or, I set a normal URL to [href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#href) attribute as shown below, then the error was solved:

```html
<a href="/account/two_factor/setup/">Two factor setup</a>
```